# How do you group a dataframe by year and month?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, seaborn, data-visualization

I'm using the [omicron dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/yamqwe/omicron-covid19-variant-daily-cases) from Kaggle, and I wanted to make a seaborn lineplot of omicron cases in Czechia over time.

I did this, but the x axis label is unreadable, since every single day is put on there. Could you help me sort the dataframe, so that I could visualize only the summed cases for each month of every year?

Here's my code so far:

```
data = "..input/omicron-covid19-variant-daily-cases/covid-variants.csv"
data = data[data.variant.str.contains("Omicron")]  # a mask with only Omicron cases
data = data[data.location.str.contains("Czech")]  # mask only with cases from Czech republic

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))

plt.title("Omicron in Czech Republic")
plt.ylabel("Number of cases")

sns.lineplot(x=data.date, y=data.num_sequences_total)
```

I tried something with the groupby() method, but I only generated a series with 2 columns named "date" and don't know what to do next.

```
test = data
test.date = pd.to_datetime(data.date)
test = data.groupby([data.date.dt.year, data.date.dt.month]).num_sequences_total.sum()
test.head()
```

Please help me figure this out, I'm stuck

Comment: You might want to try pandas plotting. E.g. `data.set_index('date')['num_sequences_total'].plot()`.  If your date column is in pandas' date format, pandas will take care of nice labeling.

Answer (score 0):

i always use this to grouping year and month
example:

GB=DF.groupby([(DF.index.year),(DF.index.month)]).sum()